# Different row tpl for every row in a view?

Tags: 7, views, theming

Can I create a different row template for every row in a view? Something like views-view-fields--foobar--0.tpl.php, views-view-fields--foobar--1.tpl.php and so on?
My goal is to create a slideshow width different template for every frame.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box with views? No. The row templates apply to all the rows in a given view.

You could do something like this with a custom module though...

You can use [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to step through your view, like so:

```
function mymod_views_pre_render(&$view){
    if($view->name == "yourviewname"){
      $count = 0;
      foreach($view->result as &$row){
          $row->template = dostuffhere($row, $count);
          $count ++;
      }
    }
}
```

In this example, you would step through each of the result rows and and create printable content. The `dostuffhere()` function would be a routing function that would load in the appropriate template files, which you could define using [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) (example on how to call with a template file is in the [comments](https://api.drupal.org/comment/27134#comment-27134)). The custom .tpl.php files from hook_theme could be called like with the [theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) function.

The routing function would then look something like this:

```
function dostuffhere($data, $row){
switch ($row) {
    case 0:
        return theme('mymodule_template1', array('$row'=>data));
        break;
    case 1:
        return theme('mymodule_template2', array('$row'=>data));
        break;
    //etc...
}
```

Because, in this example, we're using reference variables in hook_views_pre_render, the "template" variable will become available in the row output for the view. So all you really need to do in your row view is to just print out the $template var.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't know hot to access to the data passed to the template. My theme hook return this array:
    'slideshow_1' => array('variables' =>  'row' => NULL), 'template' => 'views-view-fields--slideshow'))
But I can't find any $row variable in the template.

Answer (score 0):

you can able to create a different template foe the fields which are present in the view, you can find the field template reference in , go to advanced tab in the you can able to find **Theme:Information** by clicking the Information Text you can able to find the template for every fields that are available in the view....